# JSF / Richfaces Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces, tabpanel

In a Tabpanel each Tab's content is fetched from the server by ajax (using the `switchType="ajax"` attribute) so that all the content does not have to be fetched at the start. After the content is fetched once, though, it should not be fetched from the server again since the content is already present on the page. The content of the Tab should should just be toggled between `display:none` and `display:block` as it would be if the `switchType`were set to `client`

Is there a way to tell JSF/Richfaces not to send the second ajax request if the content has already been fetched and instead just toggle the visibility?

Asked onther way: is it possible to use the `switchType="ajax"` on the first request and `switchType="client"` for the following requests?

Comment: If you don't expect the content to change there's no point in using ajax. Is there any significant difference in load times?

Comment: It takes 3x as long to load everything from the start and the user may not even click on the other tabs, so I'd like to load the content on-demand i.e. with ajax. Since the ajax requests also take some time I would like to only do it once, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep a flag for every tab that decides the switchType, e.g.

```
<rich:tab header="tab1" action="#{bean.switchTab(0)}" 
    switchType="#{bean.tabList[0] ? 'client' : 'ajax'}">Content</rich:tab>
```

You'll start with `switchType="ajax"` but when you load the tab it will be rerendered with `switchType="client"`.